# How to discover the abap development objects' properties?

Tags: reflection, abap, discoverability

I'm comming from the java world, and i'd like to know if there's anything that can help me understand the properties of abap development objects.... something like reflection.

Knowing that everything that goes on in ABAP is persisted somewhere inside a database, i'd like to know how would i go about finding out HOW and WHERE an object is saved.

For instance, i'd like to know if there are any functions that enumerate the fields of a structure, or enumerate the properties of an object, or if there's no such thing (but the properties still exist obviously), then what table would be holding those (so that i can create my own functions, or classes)

Also any other discoverability tricks that you know are good... I know this question is a little generic, but since i'm new to abap, i don't really know what to ask :P

Thx, you guys rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for something like reflection, take a look at [RTTI](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENRTTI.htm). This cvers the runtime structure of most of the stuff you'll come across. If you want to find out what's going on underneath the surface of the cevelopment tools, just turn on the SQL trace (ST05), open the object in question in an editor and check what tables are accessed...

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer your question, maybe it would be easier, if you split it up in multiple questions with some specific task you want.

Some topics I remember (please verify it, I can't check it in the moment if I remember correct):

DDIC-objects are stored in tables with `DD*`.

Tables (and there properties) are stored in `dd02l`, `dd02t` includes the texts. `dd03l` contains the fields. `dd04tl` contains the texts of data element.

But it will not help you, if you add something to this tables. The database in background will not get the definitions.

If you want to create some dynmaic *magic* you may take a look to the `field-symbols` and `assign`-command.

Comment: thx for the tip. and unfortunatelly i wasn't able to give more info, because i'm only just starting out, and have no idea what's out there, but this info should get me going faster.